# .Как сделать выпадающее меню?

Tags: java

[image: К примеру я хочу нажать на кнопку "информация о шоколаде" как мне сделать так, чтобы кнопка работала, так еще и внутри приделать меню(добавить пару пунктов)]

К примеру я хочу нажать на кнопку "информация о шоколаде" как мне сделать так, чтобы кнопка работала, так еще и внутри приделать меню(добавить пару пунктов)

Answer (score 0):

Создать новый диалог и при нажатии на кнопку сделать yourDialog.setVisible(true)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй этот код запустить

```
class MyWindow extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JTextBox textBox = new JTextBox("some text here");
    JButton button = new JButton("Click!");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, textBox.getText());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=swing+java+button+click&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8